# How to use drawText on FXCanvas in FXRuby?

Tags: ruby, fxruby

I am trying to make text appear on a FXCanvas. when I use this code:

```
def score_box(event)
FXDCWindow.new(@canvas) do |dc|

    dc.drawText(640, 450, @score)
end     
end
```

but it gives me an error saying I need to select a font, how do I do this? or could you provide anyway to make text on a canvas? Thanks

-bipolarpants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select an FXFont object into the device context (dc), e.g.

```
FXDCWindow.new(@canvas) do |dc|
  font = FXFont.new(...)
  font.create
  dc.font = font
  dc.drawText(640, 450, @score)
end
```

Comment: So now I get no error (cool!) but no visible words are seem to be displayed in the FXCanvas. I changed the font to 24 and made the x and y in the middle so I could clearly see it if it were there.

Comment: I figure it out, the color must have been set to white, all I had to do was change it to another one.